# How can we fix Installation request for google/cloud-firestore v0.2.0 error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, google-cloud-firestore

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore v0.2.0 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v0.2.0].
>       - google/cloud-firestore v0.2.0 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install ext-grpc on your system based on operating system and config PHP to load this extension:

for Unix based operating system use following command by pecl:

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

Follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc) to know fully steps of configuration gRPC for PHP:

Comment: I already did. Then this happened 

pecl/grpc is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.19.0RC1
install failed

Comment: Run php -i to see is extension loaded or not

Answer (score 2):

first, install the below package

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

then add this to composer.json:

```
"provide": { "ext-grpc": "*" },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix this issue.

1. Check the grpc extension already installed or not

   php -m | grep grpc
2. If it installed, it should give an output as `grpc` in the terminal. If it does not give any output, it means you need to install it using the following command.

   sudo apt-get install php<your_php_version>-grpc

In my case I used php7.4 then,

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-grpc
```

Normally, after this problem should be fixed. If it's not, try

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

Here are the references for this issue https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#php-implementation